# MySQL row number confusion

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

So I looked up how to simulate the row_number function from oracle in mysql and came across this: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/27/simulating-the-sql-row_number-function/

My question is how does the COUNT(*) keep going up for each of the type groups. Doesn't it get reset for each of the different `variety`s since that is the second part of the group by?

Comment: no because its `group by l.variety` and not `r.variety` which is column from different table. So `l.variety` gets new value for every row and it's compared with all `r.variety` column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the join condition `l.variety >= r.variety`. This adds rows from `l` to the result set for all varieties on the first in the `r` set, then one less, then one less, etc. Run the query without the `GROUP BY` and you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

group by will not reset since grouping is done using both columns. Basically table which is formed after join has that many entries so count goes up.

Following condition "and l.variety >= r.variety " in query limits no of rows, 
'fuji' being first and 'limbertwig' being last in alphabetical order decides the count

So in absence of above condition count(*) would have been equal = 3.